# c_void_p value to void*

Tags: python, c, ctypes, cython

I have defined ctypes struct, sommething like this:

```
class MyStruct(Structure):
    _fields_ = [('x', ctypes.c_ulonglong), ('y', ctypes.c_ulonglong)]
```

Then I make ctypes struct object in python, and pass that object to cython function.

```
struct_instance = MyStruct(4, 2)
some_cy_func(struct_instance)
```

In cython function I need call C function which accepts parameter of MyStruct type. We need to pass parameter by value, not by reference. The call to function will be with cython, not via ctypes.

My question is, how can I get actual value of C struct from ctypes, and then pass it to C function with cython.

Currently I have sommething like this:

```
ptr = ctypes.cast(ctypes.addressof(struct_instance), ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_void_p))
prt_content = ptr.contents
```

In prt_content I have c_void_p(4), but that doesn't help me. Does anyone knows some way how to pass cytpes structure to C function wrapped via cython, or maybe this isn't possible at all?

Answer (score 1):

Cython doesn't know about ctypes. You'll have to use a Cython struct:

```
cdef struct MyStruct:
    unsigned long long x
    unsigned long long y

cdef MyStruct struct_instance

struct_instance.x = 4
struct_instance.y = 2

some_cy_func(struct_instance)
```

Comment: Actually isn't need to rewrite to cython struct. We can get C struct value. It's simple, we need only to dereference ctypes.addressof(struct_instance)